# Keep on getting error 408 when registering FreeSWITCH to X-Lite

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, freeswitch

I'm a newbie to VoIP and only have limited knowledge of unix. So I've been following this [article](http://clintberry.com/2011/getting-started-with-plivo) to set up a test workaround for company's telephony application. I installed Ubuntu on Mac OS X with Virtual Box, somehow just got stuck at step 5. I got error 408 when trying to register extension in X-Lite, the soft phone I used. I searched about similar issues and seems error 408 is related to a domain problem. The author only mentioned "login to your FreeSWITCH install by extension and IP address". I guess my question is which IP address should I use as the domain? The IP address of the guest OS and or the host OS? I tried both and neither of them worked though. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow is a site for software programming questions, and your question belongs rather to Serverfault.com.

In regards to IP addresses, your FreeSWITCH server should be reachable for the SIP client. So, you need to organize your network settings in a way that external hosts in the LAN can connect to the FreeSWITCH. I don't know if it's supported in MacOS, but VirtualBox should be configured in bridge mode, so that the guest OS gets an IP address from the physical LAN.

Comment: Hi Stanislav, thanks a lot for the help. Actually I did post the same question in serverfault before I posted here. But it seems the traffic there is really low so I reposted here. And I figured it out by creating a new virtual machine and setting network adapter attached to Bridged Adapter right after I posted the question, which is exactly the same thing you mentioned I guess. I still appreciate your help a lot though, especially you are the only one that tried to help.